# How to find breaking complexity of N bit sequence?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, randomness, information-theory

I do have a secret generation source with very low bit rate. In order to guarantee secrecy I need to wait till I have say 128 samples.

How do I justify regarding brute force breaking in for $N$ bit sequence where $N<128$? How do we do such calculations for state of art computation targeted to different classes of devices?

As example if I have 48 bit secret and Eve has to do brute force. We say Eve can guess with complexity of $\mathcal{O}(2^{48})$ and it will take $t$ amount of time to break it given certain computation power.
How do we do this and till what level of $t$ is ok?

Comment: Can you expand your question a bit? It is hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Sure edited the question.

Comment: For a current well known symmetric encryption you sort of halve the brute forcing time for each bit of the key you take away.  40 bits is considered way too low since the 1990s.

Comment: If you have an algorithm and want to try out $2^{48}$ combinations for its input, it's necessary to state how long one calculation takes. If you know that number, multiply it with $2^{48}$. Anything else depends on what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various guidelines for this - it very much depends on how 'secret' the data is you are trying to protect and for how long it should be protected.

The secrecy level is relevant because it determines how much computational power is required to secure your data. The more secret something is, the stronger the encryption should be - even if this means encrypting and decrypting will take longer.

Related to this is the retention period: for long-term secrets, the encryption should be even stronger, as processing power increases over time. Something that takes one year to brute force today might take less than an hour in a few year's time.

A good overview of recommendations based on these two factors can be found on [keylength.com](https://www.keylength.com/en/3/).